# Basic HTML and CSS banner

Tags: html, css

With the example HTML / CSS below, I cannot work out why this doesnt display the expected results in any browser (hosted in Visual Studio), however works perfectly when done as a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyLxuL2y/). I'm probably missing something pretty obvious, but can anyone point out what that might be?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <p>Random white text which should appear in a grey banner at the top of the page.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #292929;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

EDIT: I have tried this in various different browsers, including Firefox, Direfox Dev Edition, Edge, and IE, all with the same results (just plan black text on white screen).

Comment: You cut out the relevant part, which is how you include the CSS file in the HTML.

Comment: I am ashamed of myself. Thanks @JJJ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to link your css file to your html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
...
```